# Interface bonding on GRE tunnel with nmcli

Tags: bonding, gre, networkmanager, nmcli

I have two Ubuntu server-based routers and I'd like to bond (in broadcast mode, since I only care about redundancy) a radio link (where the radio equipment is connected to an Ethernet port) and a LTE channel (that uses a mPCIe modem) upon which a GRE tunnel is put.

I've read the documentation and configured netplan to use NetworkManager as renderer, and I've tried to create the bond using nmcli. It seems that I cannot add the tunnel as slave in the bonding (when setting '*type*' to '*ip-tunnel*' nmcli complains about a '*mode argument required*"), so I've added it with type "*ethernet*". However, when I try to bring the slave up I get:

```
# nmcli con add type ethernet  ifname wccp0 master bond0
Connection 'bond-slave-wccp0' (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) successfully added.

# nmcli con up bond-slave-wccp0
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

Unfortunately, due to some routing policies out of my control, I cannot get rid of the tunnel.

How can I set up such an interface bonding?

Answer (score 0):

After searching the whole day, it seems that the issue is due to a bug reintroduced in the Linux kernel after the 3.17 version. The tunnel has no MAC address, and this is not supported while bonding. Fixing by hand the kernel seems to be the only solution.

More info here: https://forum.archive.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=66951